# Return random sublist uniformly

Tags: random

I want to be able to return a random sublist in a uniform distribution.

Given a list of size N and a function getRandomSubList that is called X time. We need to make sure that getRandomSubList has returned all possible unique sublists equally.

For example, if we call getRandomSubList 16 times, and our list is [1,2,3] then we want to end up in a state where approximately:

() is returned twice

(1) is returned twice

(2) is returned twice

(3) is returned twice

(1,2) is returned twice

(1,3) is returned twice

(2,3) is returned twice

(1,2,3) is returned twice

Is this possible? All the ways I could think of include returning (1,2) and (2,1) twice which is not what I want here.

- Note that [a,b] is equivalent to [b,a].

Comment: Iterate over the list and, for each element, add it to the sublist with probability 1/2.  Doesn't that do the right thing?

Comment: Huh, I think you're right, not sure why I missed this - thanks!

Comment: See this for some background on why Nate is right: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set#Properties